# Hibernate selecting data for spesific column with detached criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao, detachedcriteria

I have a simple service method to get customer from db when the customer name is 'John'.But customer name is not primary key so i cannot use getbyid kind of stuff.

My dao class name is **customerDao** and i have such a method in my **service** class:

```
public boolean isCustomerIdBiggerThanFive(String customerName) {
    // i need something like customerDao.getByName... bla bla(customerName);
}
```

and my daoClass is extending **EntityDaoImpl**

like

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImp extends EntityDaoImpl<Customer, Long> implements CustomerDao {

//some method i need here for getting data for spesific column name.
}
```

I want to use **detached criteria** but i have no idea how to achieve it. I don't want to achieve it by using custom sql query in dao class.